# Can we make network calls in JUnit?

Tags: networking, junit

```
 @Test
fun runColorMatchDetails():Unit {

    val timeout = 2000
    val addresses = InetAddress.getAllByName("www.google.com")
    for (address in addresses) {
        if (address.isReachable(timeout))
            System.out.printf("%s is reachable%n", address)
        else
            System.out.printf("%s could not be contacted%n", address)
    }


}

java.net.ConnectException: No route to host (connect failed)
at java.net.Inet6AddressImpl.isReachable0(Native Method)
at java.net.Inet6AddressImpl.isReachable(Inet6AddressImpl.java:77)
at java.net.InetAddress.isReachable(InetAddress.java:502)
at java.net.InetAddress.isReachable(InetAddress.java:461)
```

I wanna run some network calls (RestAPI) using JUnit.
this the error I am getting,I am so glad to hear back. Thanks

Comment: Usually it is better to mock those external calls, to focus more on your code unit testing. There are several mocking frameworks you can use along with JUnit, like mockito.

Comment: Thanks,I do Mocking for network calls. But I wanna do some test on these API calls to figure out which one is working or not.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Can we make network calls in JUnit?

Of course you can. JUnit is nothing but a *framework* to help with automating the execution of test methods.

What these methods actually is their own business.

Beyond that: the *broad* definition of unit tests is: "a test that does something". But there is also a more narrow one, that stresses that unit tests are about testing small units in isolation.

In other words: you can use JUnit to drive "narrow" unit tests where all your external dependencies are somehow "stubbed" (for example using mocking frameworks such as Mockito). But you can also use JUnit to drive "pure functional" test cases, that try to access whatever they want.

Thus: when you write a test that does a real network access, you can use JUnit to drive that test case. And assuming that your network settings allow for it, that test case should pass. When your test is failing, then that isn't caused by JUnit, but by some problem with your setup.